# Implementing availabilities in fullcalendar

Tags: angular, fullcalendar

In my company we tested to use fullcalendar to create an online calendar for our users.
Actually we are letting our B2B users put slots of availabilities. These availabilities are letting their client to book an appointment.

But after a user research during several months we identified that the UX/UI method to display availability slots are not the best. So we design a new userflow to improve it.

**Flow used today:**

1. When a user adds slots to be available today between 9am to 12 pm, our system is adding 6 slots of 30 minutes.

Here's a screenshot about what we have today:

[image: Here's a screenshot about what we have today:]

**Flow that we want to use:**

2. When a user adds slots to be available today between 9am to 12 pm, we want to add 1 slot between 9am to 12pm which their client to book an appointment.

Here's a screen about what we want to have:

[image: Here's a screen about what we want to have:]

Do you guys already resolve this kind of situation in using fullcalendar? Or do you think it will not work with fullcalendar (so you advice us to develop a new calendar?)

Comment: Does it mean, in that example, that the user must always book a 3-hour appointment starting at 9am? Yes you could do that with fullCalendar. There are various ways to achieve it potentially, depending on the precise details of your requirements.

Comment: @ADyson thans for your answer! No the client must not book a 3-hour appointment. The duration will depend on what type of appointment he choose. The user put availabilities slots on his agenda and the client can book one type of appointment with a specific duration for each.

Comment: Ok. So you just want to show a general period of availability? In fullCalendar for that you either use the businessHours option - this works well if you have a fixed pattern of availability every week - or you can use Background Events to highlight areas of the calendar where selections can be made. (You can then use that in conjunction with the selection options to constrain selections to only be made in areas within those background events, if necessary. People have asked very similar questions about that on this site previously, if you look under the fullcalendar tag.)